# Unable to insert values into mysql table

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm able to fetch all the values but im grtting problem while inserting the values

I'm getting problem while inserting the data into the database from an xml file and my code is

```py
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
value=[temp,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5,temp6]
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO measdata(measInfo,granPeriod,measType,measValue,r,suspect)VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",value)
mydb.commit()

print("Data inserted successfully.")
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Square brackets? maybe, common parenthesis must be used? See [MySQL Connector/Python Developer Guide  /  ...  /  MySQLCursor.execute() Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), first example.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't interpolating your string, you're just placing variable next to the query.

`VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",value)`

That's just won't work, because you aren't using `%` operator for your string to take arguments, and even if you do - you're passing single variable, while being a `list` - that's still one variable, not six.

One way to do that correctly is to convert your `list` to `str` and then pass it to your query string.
Other - to pass each item of your list individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this,

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO measdata(measInfo,granPeriod,measType,measValue,r,suspect) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
%(temp, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6))
mydb.commit()
print("Data inserted successfully.")
```

Have a look at this link for more information as mentioned in comments section.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html